# Webscraping with Python ( beginner)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm doing the first example of the webscraping tutorial from the book "Automate the Boring Tasks with Python". The project consists of typing a search term on the command line and have my computer automatically open a browser with all the top search results in new tabs

It mentions that I need to locate the

```
<h3 class="r">
```

element from the page source, which are the links to each search results. 
The r class is used only for search result links.

But the problem is that I can't find it anywhere, even using Chrome Devtools. Any help as to where is it would be greatly appreciated.

Note: Just for reference this is the complete program as seen on the book.

```
# lucky.py - Opens several Google search results.

import requests, sys, webbrowser, bs4

print('Googling..') # display text while downloading the Google page
res= requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
res.raise_for_status()

#Retrieve top searh result links.
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)

#Open a browser tab for each result.
linkElems = soup.select('.r a')
numOpen = min(5,len(linkElems))
for i in range(numOpen):
    webbrowser.open('http://google.com' + linkElems[i].get('href'))
```

Comment: Google probably changed that. Use the dev tools and search for the result links, likely still an `h3` element. Make note of the class name. This is what you should be using. Though when I check a google results page is does give me a `<h3 class='r'>`. Try right-clicking on a result link, and select `inspect`.

Comment: `'http://google.com.search>q='` does not look correct.

Comment: I'm going into the 'search' tab from the DevTools and typing <h3 class='r'> unfortunately there's zero results with it..

Comment: Sorry let me edit the typos, I'll update the corrected program.

Comment: so find you data in html and see what tag/class it use now. Page can use JavaScript/Ajax to add data and requests/BS doesn't do it.

Comment: Find it like I described about. The search does not work well here.

Comment: Thanks I found it. I was clicking inspect on the whole page, not on the actual link. Dumb mistake  but anways thanks a lot @Tammo Heeren

Comment: The search URl should be like this : "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%s&num=%d"%(search+string,int(num))

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you :

```
>>> import requests
>>> from lxml import html
>>> r = requests.get("https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how+to+do+web+scraping&num=10")
>>> source = html.fromstring((r.text).encode('utf-8'))
>>> links = source.xpath('//h3[@class="r"]//a//@href')
>>> for link in links:
        print link.replace("/url?q=","").split("&sa=")[0]
```

Output :

```
http://newcoder.io/scrape/intro/
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/10/beginner-guide-web-scraping-beautiful-soup-python/
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/
http://webscraper.io/
https://blog.hartleybrody.com/web-scraping/
https://first-web-scraper.readthedocs.io/
https://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DE7wB__M9fdw
http://www.gregreda.com/2013/03/03/web-scraping-101-with-python/
http://analystcave.com/web-scraping-tutorial/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping
```

**Note**: *I am using Python 2.7.X , for Python 3.X you just have to surround the print output like this* **print (link.replace("/url?q=","").split("&sa=")[0])**